# asp.net querystring

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

I have the following page querystring:

```
 register.aspx?id="jSmith"
```

I have the following code to retrieve the value of ID

```
    string qString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) ? string.Empty : HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

When I view the value of qString I get something like

```
    "\"jSmith\""
```

so when I do the following:

```
     if (qString == "jSmith")
     {
        ........

     }
```

it does not not execute the if condition. What do I need to do s that it does not have the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the correct way to give the path in this case would be `register.aspx?id=jSmith`, without the quotes. If you need spaces, or other special characters, in your ID, these should be URL encoded (and will be decoded by your code), but *not* enclosed in quotes.

For example, if your id was the string `john smith`, the URL would become `register.aspx?id=john+smith`, since `+` is the URL encoding of a space.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct.
The problem is that you are passing to the page `"jSmith"` with the double quotes as part of the string.
Try invoke the page this way

```
register.aspx?id=jSmith
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put quotes around values in querystring, by definition they're all strings...

Your querystring should look like :

```
register.aspx?id=jSmith
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the quotation marks in your querystring.

It should read

```
register.aspx?id=jSmith
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look for

```
if (qString == "\"jSmith\"")
```

the `\` is escaping the extra `"`

or you could perform a replace to remove the extra `"`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 Response.Redirect("Qstring.aspx?name= smith");
```

and on the page Qstring.aspx load event

```
 string s=Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();
```

gives u "smith" in s variable